# Pandas read_csv import results in error

Tags: python, csv, pandas

My csv is as follows (MQM Q.csv):

```
Date-Time,Value,Grade,Approval,Interpolation Code 
31/08/2012 12:15:00,,41,1,1 
31/08/2012 12:30:00,,41,1,1 
31/08/2012 12:45:00,,41,1,1 
31/08/2012 13:00:00,,41,1,1 
31/08/2012 13:15:00,,41,1,1 
31/08/2012 13:30:00,,41,1,1 
31/08/2012 13:45:00,,41,1,1 
31/08/2012 14:00:00,,41,1,1 
31/08/2012 14:15:00,,41,1,1
```

The first few lines have no "Value" entries but they start later on.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd 
from StringIO import StringIO
Q = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""/cygdrive/c/temp/MQM Q.csv"""), header=0, usecols=["Date-Time", "Value"], parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True, index_col=0)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "daily.py", line 4, in <module>
    Q = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""/cygdrive/c/temp/MQM Q.csv"""), header=0, usecols=["Date-Time", "Value"], parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True, index_col=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.14.0-py2.7-cygwin-1.7.30-x86_64.egg/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 443, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.14.0-py2.7-cygwin-1.7.30-x86_64.egg/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 228, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.14.0-py2.7-cygwin-1.7.30-x86_64.egg/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 533, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.14.0-py2.7-cygwin-1.7.30-x86_64.egg/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 670, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.14.0-py2.7-cygwin-1.7.30-x86_64.egg/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1067, in __init__
    col_indices.append(self.names.index(u))
ValueError: 'Value' is not in list
```

Comment: Can you format your data or provide a link to it as I cannot reproduce your error and it's unclear where the formatting is failing

Comment: Erm, why are you calling StringIO on the filename?

Comment: The following worked for me: `pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp),header=0, usecols=["Date-Time", "Value"], parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True, index_col=0)` so is the problem you are using StringIO when it is unnecessary?

Comment: Could you clarify what io and temp are set to?

Comment: @EdChum I tried removing the StringIO but then I get an error saying "ValueError: 'Date-Time' is not in list"

Comment: Can you post a link to the data as your pasted data worked, also try this `pd.read_csv('/cygdrive/c/temp/MQM Q.csv',header=0, usecols=["Date-Time", "Value"], parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True, index_col=0)`

Comment: [link to file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9q0tbxskwK2aEYzQlkwLUp0QVk/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Trying your code resulted in an error saying "ValueError: 'Date-Time' is not in list"

Comment: @user1571934 no, ed's code is correct (works on 0.14.0). What version of pandas are you using? The other option is not to use usecols (and just select the columns you want after reading).

Comment: There is something strange here, I can reproduce your error using your params but if I just plain load it, it works ok: `df=pd.read_csv('MQM Q.csv')`, if I pass 'Date-Time' to use for `usecols` param then I get the same error

Comment: I'm using 0.14.0 on cygwin. @EdChum Code works if i remove all options as well.

Comment: I think this is a bug but I can't explain it, your csv is encoded using `utf-8`, I tried to see what happens if we change the encoding to `ANSI` and it loaded without error, then I tried `utf-8 without BOM` and it worked, then I tried `utf-8` again and it failed (Iused notepad++ to do the conversions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with the csv parser, firstly this works:

```
df = pd.read_csv('MQM Q.csv')
```

also this works:

```
df = pd.read_csv('MQM Q.csv', usecols=['Value'])
```

but if I want `Date-Time` then it fails with the same error message as yours.

So I noticed it was utf-8 encoded and so I converted using notepad++ to ANSI and it worked, I then tried utf-8 without BOM and it also worked.

I then converted it to utf-8 (presumably there is now a BOM) and it failed with the same error as before, so I don't think you are imaging this now and this looks like a bug.

I am using python 3.3, pandas 0.14 and numpy 1.8.1

To get around this do this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('MQM Q.csv', usecols=[0,1], parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True, index_col=0)
```

This will set your index to the Date-Time column which will correctly convert to a datetimeindex.

```
In [40]:

df.index
Out[40]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2012-08-31 12:15:00, ..., 2013-11-28 10:45:00]
Length: 43577, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

Comment: Man, a big +1 for mentioning the BOM issue. I don't know how many times I've struggled with this 'error'. Just saved re-saved a file with UTF no BOM and it worked immediately.

Comment: @djnz0feh i think in actuality it should just work if you pass `encoding='utf-8'` now: `df = pd.read_csv('MQM Q.csv', usecols=[0,1], parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True, index_col=0, encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: Should put that in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your code should read (no need from StringIO on the filename!):

```
import pandas as pd 
Q = pd.read_csv("/cygdrive/c/temp/MQM Q.csv"), header=0, usecols=["Date-Time", "Value"], parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True, index_col=0)
```

Otherwise/currently pandas is trying to read the string (*of the path*) in as a DataFrame:

```
In [11]: pd.read_csv(StringIO("""/cygdrive/c/temp/MQM Q.csv"""))
Out[11]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [/cygdrive/c/temp/MQM Q.csv]
Index: []
```

which obviously isn't what you want (hence you see the Value is not a column exception).

Comment: I get the following error with your line of code...
`ValueError: 'Date-Time' is not in list`

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me (I have the CSV file in the same directory as the script, but that should not matter). I am running the following script on my Mac, not Cygwin, but it should work the same way:

```
import pandas as pd 
Q = pd.read_csv("MQM Q.csv",
        header=0,
        parse_dates=True, 
        dayfirst=True,
        index_col=0,
        usecols=["Date-Time", "Value"])
print Q
```

## Discussion

- StringIO will not work, unless you create a new StringIO object with the contents of the file, not the name of the file.
- I don't have any problem with the "Date-Time" column. In fact, there is not error running the previous code at all.