# Pandas ValueError: 'Date' is not in list

Tags: python, pandas, vim, encoding, utf-8

I am going through the Pandas "cook book" chapter 1, bikes.csv example. When I try to change parse_dates to ['Date'], dayfirst=True, index_col to date like this:
*(at line: In [6], in the cook book's 1st chapter)*

```
fixed_df = pd.read_csv('../data/bikes.csv', sep=';', encoding='latin1', parse_dates=['Date'], dayfirst=True, index_col='Date')
```

I get this:
***ValueError: 'Date' is not in list.***
Before I write here, I try these solutions:

**1st:** [utf-8 bom problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24293745/pandas-read-csv-import-results-in-error)

As I understand, bom with in the utf-8 creates some problem and cause this error. In addition "Dates" line is accepted as a `tuple` by pandas while reading? (so sorry if I write it with wrong words, but this what I remember and I am not pro at Python) I try to convert encoding with this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898294/convert-utf-8-with-bom-to-utf-8-with-no-bom-in-python):
the "utf-8-sig" codec gives a unicode string without the BOM:

```
fp = open("file.txt")
s = fp.read()
u = s.decode("utf-8-sig")
```

Even I did not get any error, it did not work.

**2nd:** [Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets)
I try these to change encoding

```
iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1 infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

and this,

```
vim +"set nobomb | set fenc=utf8 | x" filename.txt
```

None of them works.

**3rd:** I try to change the file encoding when I open it with [vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507777/vim-set-encoding-and-fileencoding-utf-8).

`set fileencoding=utf-8-sig` (and other possible codings like ANSI, ASCII etc.)
I get this error

> E213: Cannot convert (add ! to write without conversion)

Would you please help me, where do I miss? Many thanks in advance

Comment: `parse_dates=True` doesn't work?

Comment: Try `pd.read_csv('../data/bikes.csv', sep=';', encoding='utf-8-sig', parse_dates=['Date'], dayfirst=True, index_col='Date')` or `pd.read_csv('../data/bikes.csv', sep=';', encoding='utf-16', parse_dates=['Date'], dayfirst=True, index_col='Date')`

Comment: `pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jvns/pandas-cookbook/master/data/bikes.csv', sep=';', encoding='latin1', parse_dates=['Date'], dayfirst=True, index_col='Date')`  works fine with Python 3.5 pandas 0.20.3.

Comment: @COLDSPEED yes, parse_dates=True doesn't work.

Comment: @MaxU I try first, utf-8-sig it throws 'ValueError: 'Date' is not in list'. And try your second suggestion, utf-16 it gives the error: 'UnicodeError: UTF-16 stream does not start with BOM'

Comment: @ayhan, i just checked it under Pandas 0.20.1 - it works fine as well...

Comment: @Z.Grey, about using `parse_dates=True` - i'd also add `index_col=0`...

Comment: @MaxU I use also pandas-0.20.1 but it does not work, I get this "Date is not in the list" error

Comment: @Z.Grey, are you using the same CSV file as from ayhan's comment?

Comment: @MaxU No my file is comptagevelo2012.csv here is the link of file [link ] (http://donnees.ville.montreal.qc.ca/dataset/f170fecc-18db-44bc-b4fe-5b0b6d2c7297/resource/d54cec49-349e-47af-b152-7740056d7311/download/comptagevelo2012.csv)

Comment: @MaxU By the way I try also  'index_col=0' with in this code '(...sep=";", encoding="latin1", parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True, index_col=0 usecols=["Date-Time", "Value"])' it give the "ValueError: Usecols do not match names." I use it also without 'usecols', and well at least it did not give any error, but I can not modified the date

Comment: @ayhan I got some http error, not found. I try this example from Spyder, not Jupiter maybe that's why I get this error, I don't know. Thus, I download the file, before trying this example.

Comment: @Z.Grey the http error is because of the formatting in the comments so I posted an answer instead. Try the code in the answer.

Comment: @ayhan, ooh that's right, and I try your answer and it works. Thank you also for your explanation part in the answer, it clarifies the things in my head, many thanks

Comment: @Z.Grey You are welcome. Glad that it worked. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the URL you provided

```
url = 'http://donnees.ville.montreal.qc.ca/dataset/f170fecc-18db-44bc-b4fe-5b0b6d2c7297/resource/d54cec49-349e-47af-b152-7740056d7311/download/comptagevelo2012.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(url, sep=',', parse_dates={'datetime':[0, 1]}, index_col='datetime')

df.head()
```

gives

```
            Rachel / Papineau  Berri1  Maisonneuve_2  Maisonneuve_1  Brébeuf  \
datetime                                                                       
2012-01-01                 16      35             51             38      5.0   
2012-02-01                 43      83            153             68     11.0   
2012-03-01                 58     135            248            104      2.0   
2012-04-01                 61     144            318            116      2.0   
2012-05-01                 95     197            330            124      6.0
```

I have changed both the `sep`  and `encoding`  arguments because the separator in that file is comma and the encoding is `utf-8` (the default value for `read_csv`). There is an unnamed column for time, you can use that to include in parsing too. In this example I think they are all zero but this might be useful in other cases.